# AccessのSQLでDateAdd関数と日付を比較すると『比較条件の型が一致しません』とのエラー

Tags: sql, ms-access

お世話になります。

MicrosoftAccess2010でSQLを記述しているときに、現在の日時(`NOW()`)と、日付フィールドの値を`DATEADD`で加算した日付を比較すると、『比較条件の型が一致しません』とのエラーになります。

DATEADD関数が返す値は日付型だったと思うのですが、これがなぜエラーなのかが解りません。
原因と対策をお教えいただけますでしょうか。

記述はこのようになっています。

```
SELECT * FROM tmp1 WHERE NOW() < DATEADD('m',7,visited_dt<日付型のフィールドyyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ssの形式>)
↑失敗

SELECT * FROM tmp1 WHERE NOW() < visited_dt
↑これならOK、まぁ当たり前ですが。

SELECT * FROM tmp1 WHERE NOW() < CDATE(DATEADD('m',7,visited_dt))
↑これもNG。エラー内容は同じ

UPDATE tmp1 SET a = DATEADD('m',7,visited_dt)
SELECT * FROM tmp1 WHERE NOW() < a
↑二回に分けて行った結果、これならOK。
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access2016で検証してみました。
クエリではDateaddしても結果は返しましたがVBAでは多分失敗すると思います。

理由は下記になります。
https://support.office.com/ja-jp/article/dateadd-%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19
ここを参照すると戻り値はVariant型になっています。

今回実行しようとしているSQLの形にしようとするならば一度Dateadd後に日付型に意図的に変換した後に実行する方法が簡単だと思います。

```
Dim visited_dt As Date
Dim AddDate_dt As Date

visited_dt = #5/20/2019#
AddDate_dt = DateAdd("m", 7, visited_dt)
```

いかがでしょうか？

追記
まずバグの可能性を疑ってみてサービスパックは適用されていますか？
https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/2687455/description-of-office-2010-service-pack-2

続いて
Access2007で再度検証してみました。
テストテーブルを作ってみました。

クエリで1行ずつ実行しました

```sql
create table tmp2 (id integer , visited_dt datetime);
insert into tmp2 values (1,#2018/10/19#);
insert into tmp2 values (2,#2018/10/20#);
insert into tmp2 values (3,#2018/10/21#);
SELECT * FROM tmp2 WHERE Now()< DateAdd('m',7,visited_dt);
```

この構成で必要な要件を満たしていればいいのですが、、、
結果は2019/05/20現在で2018/10/21のレコードのみ抽出されたのを確認しました。
上記のSQLでテストテーブルでSELECTまで確認してみてはいかがでしょうか？
実行されれば本番SQLのどこかに不具合がありそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。2016では試せないのですが、現行ではクエリでもVBA内でexecuteしても結果は同じく失敗します。2016でクエリは返す…ということは、2010特有の不具合なのでしょうか？

Comment: 一度試してみましたが、やはりうまくいきませんでした…。データ型も間違いなく日付型になっていますし、CDATEでもう一度日付型に変換してもダメ。ためしにvisited_dtをテキスト型に変換し、それをCDATEで囲むと通りました。…どういうことなのでしょうか？

Comment: 別クライアントに2010があったので試してみましたが、こちらは正常に動作しました。問題が再現しないため的確な答えができず申し訳ございません。
Officeの再インストールか修復などを行ってみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございました。最後の手段、再インストールを行ったところ、無事に動くようになりました。あまり例のないことなので驚きましたが、何とか回避できました。今後とも何かありましたらよろしくお願いいたします。